# Problem with SELECT * in MySQL through ODBC from Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: mysql, sql-server, odbc

I have a MySQL server as a linked server in Microsoft SQL Server 2008.  For the link I use MySQL ODBC Connector version 5.1.8.  When invoking queries using `OPENQUERY` (the only way I found of performing queries), problems occur. Simple queries, such as

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(MYSQL, 'SHOW TABLES')
```

work fine. Selection of individual columns, e.g.,

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(MYSQL, 'SELECT nr FROM letter')
```

works fine as well, but SELECT * syntax does not work. The query:

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(MYSQL, 'SELECT * FROM mytable')
```

raises an error:

> Msg 7347, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
>   OLE DB provider 'MSDASQL' for linked
>   server 'MYSQL' returned data that does
>   not match expected data length for
>   column '[MSDASQL].let_nr'. The
>   (maximum) expected data length is 40,
>   while the returned data length is 0.

How can I make the SELECT * syntax work?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This problem happens if you are querying a MySQL linked server and the table you query has a datatype `char()`. This means fixed length and NOT `varchar()`. This happens when your fixed length field has a shorter string than the maximum length that SQL Server expected to get from the ODBC.

To fix this go to your MySQL server and change the datatype to `varchar()` leaving the length as it is. Example change `char(10)` to `varchar(10)`.

Comment: Hi, Tarek. Thanks a lot for your response! Indeed the constant-length char() fields may be a problem. I had trouble with strings imported from MySQL where they would be seemingly padded by zeros. I can't check right now, but will try your solution today or tomorrow. Thanks!

Comment: On the other hand, using the following: exec('Select * From mytable') AT MYSQL will get the data displayed but you will not be able to join the output or select from it except if you create a temp table and export the output to it.  For that reason, I personally prefer openquery.

Comment: I just tested your solution and indeed converting CHAR fields to VARCHAR makes the error go away. Thanks a million!

Comment: God,i can't change the field type!

Comment: Instead of changing the data type on the table itself, you can just convert it on the query: CAST(MyColumn AS VARCHAR(1))

Answer (score 10):

Executing the following command before queries seems to help:

DBCC TRACEON(8765)

The error messages go away and queries seem to be working fine.

I'm not sure what it does though; I found it here: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=46857

Strangely, SQL Server becomes unstable, stops responding to queries and finally crashes  with scary-looking dumps in the logs a few minutes after several queries to the MySQL server. I am not sure if this has to do anything with the DBCC command, so I'm still interested in other possible solutions to this problem.

Comment: DBCC TRACEON(8765) solved it for me. And no instability problems either.

Comment: Works like a charm, but how?

Answer (score 4):

What I did to fix this since I can't modify the MySQL database structure is just create a view with a cast ex: `CAST(call_history.calltype AS CHAR(8)) AS Calltype`,
and select my view from MSSQL in my linked server.

The reason behind is that some strange types don't work well with the linked server (in my case the MySQL enum)

Comment: No need to do it in a view, you can do it directly in the query itself.

Answer (score 1):

I found this

> "The problem is that one of the fields
>   being returned is a blank or NULL CHAR
>   field. To resolve this in the Mysql
>   ODBC settings select the option "Pad
>   CHAR to Full Length"

Look at the last post [here](http://sql-server-performance.com/Community/forums/p/4856/31445.aspx)

Comment: I checked the option, restarted SQL Server for good measure, but the problem is still there.

Comment: It' unuseful for mysql enum type. I use mysql ODBC 5.1 driver, mysql server 5.5, sqlserver 2005.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative would be to use the trim() function in your SELECT statement within OPENQUERY. The downside is you have to list each field individually, but what I did was create a view that calls OPENQUERY and then perfrom select * on the view.

Not ideal, but better than changing data types on tables!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a crappy solution I came up with because I am unable to change the datatype to varchar as the db admin for the MySQL server is afraid it will cause issues with his scripts.

in my MySQL select query I run a case statement checking the character length of the string and add a filler character in front of the string "filling it up" to the max (in my case its a char(6)).  then in the select statement of the openquery I strip the character back off.

```
Select  replace(gradeid,'0','')  as gradeid from openquery(LINKEDTOMYSQL, '
SELECT case when char_length(gradeid) = 0 then concat("000000", gradeID)
when char_length(gradeID) = 1 then concat("00000", gradeID)
when char_length(gradeID) = 2 then concat("0000", gradeID)
when char_length(gradeID) = 3 then concat("000", gradeID)
when char_length(gradeID) = 4 then concat("00", gradeID)
when char_length(gradeID) = 5 then concat("0", gradeID)
else gradeid end as gradeid 
FROM sometableofmine')
```

it works but it probably is slower...

maybe you can make a MySQL function that will do the same logic, or come up with a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 1):

I had the similar problem to this myself, which I resolved by wrapping the column-names in single ` style quotes.

Instead of...

```
column_name
```

...use...

```
`column_name`
```

Doing this helps the MySql query-engine should the column-name clash with a key or reserved-word.*

Instead of using `SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME`, try to use all column names with quotes:

```
SELECT `column1`, `column2`, ... FROM TABLE_NAME
```

**Example for normal datatype columns**

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(MYSQL, 'SELECT `column1`, `column2`,...,`columnN` FROM mytable')
```

**Example for ENUM datatype columns**

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(MYSQL, 'SELECT `column1`, trim(`column2`) `column2`, `column3`,...,`columnN` FROM mytable')
```

*For those used to Sql Server, it is the MySql equivalent of wrapping a value in square-brackets, `[` and `]`.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. You can [search for similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search), or refer to the related and linked questions on the right-hand side of the page to find an answer. If you have a related but different question, [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), and include a link to this one to help provide context. See: [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: I have experienced the similar issue and resolve it by my answer above

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.

Comment: @Knickerless-Noggins this is not about asking a new question, this is about the answer for Gintautas Miliauskas raised at the top of the page, I have experienced the same error while retrieving MySql data from MSSQL Openquery, I just wrote how I did figure out the problem and how I did resolved it.

Comment: @Zafor Iqbal I see. It's the language barrier. I will reword your answer a little.

Comment: @Knickerless-Noggins thanks for editing my post, it's more clear now and I know now how to approach with an answer, cheers....!!!