# pulling data from MySql Server using SQL server openquery

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, type-conversion, openquery

I am trying to pull data from Mysql server using SQL server OPENQUERY function. When I run a query to count the records that are in thew mysql server I get the value no problem

```
-this query works and it return the total records found
SELECT count(*) AS total  FROM OPENQUERY(LinkedServer, 'SELECT * FROM mydb_name.users')
```

But when I do

```
SELECT login_user FROM OPENQUERY(LinkedServer, 'SELECT * FROM mydb_name.users')
```

I get this error

```
Msg 7347, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
OLE DB provider 'MSDASQL' for linked server 'LinkedServer' returned data that does not match expected data length for column '[MSDASQL].login_user'. The (maximum) expected data length is 60, while the returned data length is 16.
```

I have tried but did not work

```
SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(60), login_user) AS name  FROM OPENQUERY(LASWEB, 'SELECT * FROM mydb_name.users')
```

I am assuming it is a data type issue but how can I around it? How can I pull the data that I need?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried this -  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4215979/problem-with-select-in-mysql-through-odbc-from-microsoft-sql-server : " [in the answer] ... go to MySQL server and change the datatype to varchar() leaving the length as it is... Example, char(10) change it to varchar(10)."

Comment: @Question3CPO  That worked yes. But I don't want to change all my mysql columns from Char to varchar! Most of my tables are char and not varchar I wish you can help me finish this issue as I must keep mysql table as char.  Thanks

Comment: Is there a way you can create a duplicate table on MySQL of that data, change the data type on the duplicate table, and then move it to SQL Server, or is that not allowed?  If so, the duplicate table can be the reference point for SQL Server and you can keep the original table's column types.

Comment: I just got it to work. Here is what I had to do SELECT login_user  FROM OPENQUERY(LASWEB, 'SELECT CAST(u.login_user AS CHAR) AS login_user  FROM mydb_name.users AS u')   So I casted the value in mysql query and that did it.

Answer (score 2):

Cast the variable like so worked

```
SELECT login_user  FROM OPENQUERY(LASWEB, 'SELECT CAST(u.login_user AS CHAR) AS login_user  FROM mydb_name.users AS u')
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(LinkedServer, 'SELECT login_user FROM mydb_name.users')